# Google map InfoWindow dose not display image with predefined size

Tags: javascript, html

I some pictures need to showing in googlemap inforwindow, the inforwindow html content is as following:

```html
html='<img style="max-width: 600;height-max: 100%" src="http://www.oursteps.com.au/bbs/data/attachment/forum/201610/18/023201oqdnhzhnujp9dqzh.jpg" /><img style="max-width: 600;height-max: 100%" src="http://wwww.oursteps.com.au/bbs/data/attachment/forum/201610/18/051237g63nvqynyu6lqn6n.jpg" /><img style="max-width: 600;height-max: 100%" src="http://www.oursteps.com.au/bbs/data/attachment/forum/201610/22/051804s8uoft49zcs79cvv.jpg" /><img style="max-width: 600;height-max: 100%" src="http://www.oursteps.com.au/bbs/data/attachment/forum/201610/22/051805bbrz99olo9q755lv.jpg" />'
```

The populating the google map inforwindow like following code:

```
marker['infowindow'] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: html
            });
```

I tried to limited the width of image to 600 px which is the width of the infowindow.

if html tag above showing in normal html page, the width of image defined will apply to image properly:
[enter link description here](http://showmyroutes.com/travel_planer/plan_map.php?sights_id=137792299596,155227191264,169775616665,236981817651,253219237290,282116536568,286007269643,29877356324,31014855199,31886855061,326086433042,362828061289,372143790210,379760456342,382184585534,445810156610,452908886142,474890717305,475823421976,481612010091,495760795846,512789964474,534263600039,548924809117,552313860813,564020342464,56956342086,75593827817,85854399225&plan_name=%E5%9C%A8%E6%97%85%E9%80%94%E4%B8%AD%E6%85%A2%E6%85%A2%E5%8F%98%E8%80%81%EF%BC%8C%E6%98%AF%E4%BA%BA%E7%94%9F%E4%B8%80%E5%A4%A7%E5%B9%B8%E4%BA%8B%EF%BC%81%E5%A4%A7%E9%BE%84%E8%83%8C%E5%8C%85%E5%AE%A2%E6%90%AD%E7%81%AB%E8%BD%A6%E7%8E%AF%E6%AC%A7%E5%85%AD%E5%9B%BD%E7%BB%88%E6%9E%81%E6%B8%B8)

Image width =600 px  restriction dose not work in inforwindow properly:

[enter link description here](http://showmyroutes.com/travel_planer/plan_map.php?sights_id=137792299596,155227191264,169775616665,236981817651,253219237290,282116536568,286007269643,29877356324,31014855199,31886855061,326086433042,362828061289,372143790210,379760456342,382184585534,445810156610,452908886142,474890717305,475823421976,481612010091,495760795846,512789964474,534263600039,548924809117,552313860813,564020342464,56956342086,75593827817,85854399225&plan_name=%E5%9C%A8%E6%97%85%E9%80%94%E4%B8%AD%E6%85%A2%E6%85%A2%E5%8F%98%E8%80%81%EF%BC%8C%E6%98%AF%E4%BA%BA%E7%94%9F%E4%B8%80%E5%A4%A7%E5%B9%B8%E4%BA%8B%EF%BC%81%E5%A4%A7%E9%BE%84%E8%83%8C%E5%8C%85%E5%AE%A2%E6%90%AD%E7%81%AB%E8%BD%A6%E7%8E%AF%E6%AC%A7%E5%85%AD%E5%9B%BD%E7%BB%88%E6%9E%81%E6%B8%B8)

The image size is the original size in inforwindows although I have define the max-width as 600 px.

Could not figure how to apply width restriction on images showing in google map inforwindow.

Comment: I'v checkd the links that you provided, and I found that the pictures width is 600px! So what's the problem ?

Comment: I also see the image as 600px wide in the links your posted, but the code you posted above has issues, answer added.

Comment: I just added px after 600 which fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the code you posted...
`max-width:600` should be `max-width: 600px`.
`height-max: 100%` should be `max-height: 100%`.

```html
<img style="max-width: 600px; max-height: 100%" src="http://www.oursteps.com.au/bbs/data/attachment/forum/201610/18/023201oqdnhzhnujp9dqzh.jpg" />
```